# Tick marks: How to force powers of 10 in a ListPlot with logarithmic scale?

Tags: plotting, output-formatting, ticks, output, logarithmic-scale

I'm sure this is very simple to do, but I'm yet unable to find the trick.  Here's a simple ListPlot with a Log scale on the horizontal axis:

```
ListPlot[
    Table[
        {10^n, n},
        {n, -10, 5, 0.25}
    ],
    Frame -> True,
    PlotRange -> All,
    Joined -> True,
    Mesh -> None,
    InterpolationOrder -> 2,
    ScalingFunctions -> {"Log"}
]
```

Preview:

[image]

As you can see, the horizontal ticks are showing 0.1 and 100.  I want all the horizontal ticks to be powers of ten, so $10^{-1}$ and $10^2$, instead of 0.1 and 100.  So what's wrong with my code above?  How to fix the output?

Also, I would prefer to get powers like $10^{-9}$, $10^{-6}$, $10^{-3}$, $10^0$ (or 1 in this case), $10^3$, $10^6$ (powers in multiples of 3).

Comment: Use "Log10" rather than "Log".

Comment: @SHuisman, it works great, thanks a lot!  Is there an option to change the exponents to multiples of 3, so $10^{-9}$, $10^{-6}$, $10^{-3}$ and so on?

Comment: As of now you would have to do it manually using FrameTicks, then you have full control of the ticks. ```FrameTicks->{{Automatic,Automatic},{{10^#,Superscript[10,#]}&/@Range[-15,15,3],Automatic}}```

Comment: @SHuisman, I'm surprised that there isn't a standard option for this.  Also, using the custom FrameTicks removes the secondary Ticks, which are useful.  How to get them back?

Comment: You can add ticks with no label e.g. ```{2*10^9,"",{0.02,0}}``` to add a tick at 2*10^9 without label, and with a length of 0.02.

Comment: @SHuisman, this makes a lot of coding just to get these Ticks in multiples of 3 powers of 10!  There surely is another way in doing this, since $10^{3n}$ is relatively standard (nano, micro, milli, kilo, mega, giga, etc).

Comment: I'm quite sure there isn't, at least for now…